# understanding Layout_Weight of linear layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I am trying to create a layout which has an image view and another LinearLayout containing 2 textviews. I want the imageView to take 60% of the total layout's height and the remaining space to be acquired by the Layout of the textViews. However the problem is the height of the imageview doesn't become 60% of the total height. It changes with the dimensions of the image. I haven't been able to figure out the reason behind this behavior.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myView”
    android:layout_width="@dimen/my_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1.0"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_weight=“0.6”
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.40”
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
             >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/my_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/my_padding"
                android:text=“hello “world/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:text=“ty”/>


                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height=“match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    ></View>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/but_width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/but_height"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                    android:text=“button”

                    />

                </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

width and height of the views don't depend only from layout_weight attribute. For example it can depends from its child's sizes(if it's a view group). You must always avoid to use nested layouts because it uses more memory. Instead of the frame layout and several linear layouts you can use one relative layout.